# Android App Bundle Dynamic Feature in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, android-app-bundle

We are checking if there is a way to implement Android App Bundle Dynamic Feature in Ionic. I know the App Bundle can be done because it is related to the build. However, is the Dynamic Features available in Ionic? If yes, how?